# Наложение прозрачных PNG изображений друг на друга

Tags: c#, visual-studio, графика, png

Всем доброго времени. Столкнулся с такой проблемой : есть несколько пикчеров с разными PNG картинками на фоне. нужно наложить их друг на друга что бы последний не перекрывал более ранние. 
пробую так :

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        {
            Size = pbx_StylePic.Size;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("styles / "+ pb.Name +".png");
        };
        pbx_StylePic.Controls.Add(pb);
```

Создаю новый PictureBox в контейнер фонового пикчера но выдает ошибку :
Элемент управления не поддерживает прозрачные цвета фона.
Помогите решить задачу. Может я в коде что напутал?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        {
        RadioButton _rb = sender as RadioButton;
        string path = "styles/shirt/" + _rb + ".png";

        Image im = Image.FromFile(path);
        Graphics gr = pbx_StylePic.CreateGraphics();
        gr.DrawImage(im, new Point(0,0));
        }
```